# Rails nested routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm having three models with nested resource.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :basiccases
end

class Basiccase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :form3_c      
end

class Form3C < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :basiccases
end


resources :basiccases  do
  resources :form3_cs
  end
```

I'm trying to send the basiccase to the new form using

```
<%= link_to "ADD Form3C", new_basiccase_form3_c_path(@basiccase)%>
```

and fetch the new value in the form using

```
<%= form_for([@form3c, @basiccase]) do |f| %>
```

in new view in form_for method. 
My controller code

```
class Form3CsController <  ApplicationController
  #before_filter :authenticate

  def new
    @title = "New Form 3C"
    @basiccase = Basiccase.find_by_id(params[:id])

    @form3c = Form3C.new if signed_in?
  end

  def create       
       @form3c = @basiccase.build_form3_c(params[:form3c])
          if @form3c.save
            flash[:success] = "Form created!"
            redirect_to current_user
          else
            flash[:warning] ="Failed to create a Form"
            render 'users/show'
          end
  end
end
```

My main aim is to get the basiccase_id in the create method of form3_c controller and assign the foreign key attribute.  Is my approach correct ?
I'm getting an error

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <h1>Add Form 3C </h1>
2: <%= form_for(@basiccase) do |f| %>
3:     <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
4: 
5:     <div class="field">
```

Comment: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: for <%= form_for(@form3c, @basiccase) do |f| %>

Comment: Please edit your question, add your controller code and esp. a usable stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<%= form_for([@basiccase, @form3c]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Its still raising an error. undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class  undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class